# Hibernate filling entities with ids while persisting

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

When hibernate persists an entity, it automatically replaces the empty ID with the generated ID. That works fine, but when I persist an object that is already in the database {one of the columns is marked unique}, it doesn't return correct ID, instead it returns newly created ID. Is there a way to get right ids?

Here is what I am trying to do {added *load tags with correct ids*, trying to load all persisted tags with correct ids}:

```
// Create all tags
List<Tag> createdTags = createTags();

// Save all new tags, ignore tags that are already in the database
int error = tagService.saveTags(createdTags);

// load tags with correct ids
createdTags = tagService.getTagsByName(createdTags);

for (Tag t : createdTags) {
    logger.debug("ID: " + t.getId() + "TAGNAME: " + t.getTagName());
}

Post post;

if (visibilityComboBox.getValue().equals(visibility.getPublicValue())) {
   post = new Post(securityHelper.getLogedInUser(), message.getValue());
} else {
   post = new Post(securityHelper.getLogedInUser(), message.getValue(), Visibility.FRIENDS);
}

// Save post
postService.persist(post);

// Save posts tags
if (createdTags == null || createdTags.size() > 0) {
    PostTags postTags = new PostTags(createdTags, post);
    postTagsService.persist(postTags);
}
```

I figured there isn't so I tried to load it from the database. But that leads on my second question. Given this HQL:

```
String query = "FROM " + this.genericType.getName()
               + " AS tags WHERE tags.tagName in (:tagName)";

List<Tag> ta = (List<Tag>) session.createQuery(query).setParameterList("tagName", namesArray).list();
```

`namesArray` is an array of strings, `tags.tagName` is a string.

It always returns only the last tag in the array. Why doesn't it work?

Thanks for your answers.

[Link to repository](https://github.com/Yggdrasil88/Social-network-semestr-work)

Comment: Don't post links to code. Post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your tags have the ID of the tag already set then you can use merge.  Assuming they do not then you will have to do what you are already trying to do.

There is nothing wrong with your query.  I just tried something very similar in my data model and got the expected result.  Either namesArray is an array of length one or there is truly only one tag that matches.  Here is the query I ran:

```
HibernateQuery query = (HibernateQuery) em.createQuery("FROM Study AS s WHERE s.studyNumber in (:nums)");
query.getHibernateQuery().setParameterList("nums", new Integer[] {2, 3, 4});
List<?> result = query.getResultList();
System.out.println(result.size()); //printed 3
```

If you want to get fancy you may be able to combine the two operations into a single "query" if you use native SQL or something of that nature but unless this is a performance bottleneck I'd stick with the simpler approach first.

Also, assuming the list of tags is relatively small you could also cache them in memory to avoid a database trip on the first lookup.

Also, see: [Save object in database if it does not already exist (Hibernate & Spring)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321080/save-object-in-database-if-it-does-not-already-exist-hibernate-spring)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helped me change the approach to the problem. Now I load the tags I already have in the database and then save the ones I don't have.